# Can a New Game + player summon or be summoned by a New Game player?

Tags: dark-souls, dark-souls-remastered

I've recently started delving into the PvP side of Dark Souls Remastered for the Xbox 360, and have been testing my skills against a few friends. However I have advanced into NG+ and was trying to summon one such friend for the Iron Golem boss fight. This friend is SL 117 whilst I'm SL 123 so shouldn't be any problems there, so I just wanted to know if it was because me being in NG+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that affects summoning in Dark Souls is your SL (Level) range.  Your NG+ status doesn't affect anything in terms of multiplayer.  There is no 'official' list that I know of for SL ranges for multiplayer, but there is a [calculator you can use online](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator)(for both Remastered and original Dark Souls) to find out.

Please note that there may be a +-1 level difference in reality from the calculator because it's fan made.

> **Soul Level 123:**
>
> You can summon levels 101-145.
>
> You can be summoned by levels 103-148.

---

However, *Dark Souls Remastered* added a new aspect to the multiplayer formula: **Weapon Matchmaking.**
I suspect this is where your problem lies.

Now you must have a similar weapon level to the other player you are trying to play with, or you won't be able to join up.  Refer to the weapon level calculator by [scrolling down here](https://darksouls.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator) to see if that's what giving you trouble.  At the maximum weapon level of 15 though

> **Weapon Level: 15**
>
> You can match with weapon levels 9-15.

So if you've got a maxed out weapon you may need to switch it up if your buddy is using something lower-level.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now to be honest. He was using a +3 Dragon Tooth whilst I was using a +15 Uchigatana. Thanks~